# subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to the subprocess.call function and I have tried different combinations of the same call but it is not working.

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
cmd = 'sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n '+outpath+fnametempout+' > '+outpath+fnameout
print cmd
```

If I try the call I get an error:

```
cmd = cmd.split(" ")
print cmd
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

the error I get is:

```
sort: stat failed: >: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing it this way, you need `shell=True` to allow the shell redirection to work.

```
subprocess.call('sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n '+outpath+fnametempout,shell=True)
```

A better way is:

```
with open(outpath+fnameout,'w') as fout: #context manager is OK since `call` blocks :)
    subprocess.call(cmd,stdout=fout)
```

which avoids spawning a shell all-together and is safe from shell injection type attacks.  Here, `cmd` is a list as in your original, e.g.

```
cmd = 'sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n '+outpath+fnametempout
cmd = cmd.split()
```

It should also be stated that python has really nice sorting facilities and so I doubt that it is actually necessary to pass the job off to `sort` via a subprocess.

---

Finally, rather than using `str.split` to split the arguments, from a string, it's probably better to use `shlex.split` as that will properly handle quoted strings.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> cmd = "foo -b -c 'arg in quotes'"
>>> print cmd.split()
['foo', '-b', '-c', "'arg", 'in', "quotes'"]
>>> print shlex.split(cmd)
['foo', '-b', '-c', 'arg in quotes']
```

Comment: +1. But the `shlex` thing is a bit in the wrong direction. Building a `list` instead of a `str` in the first place is always the best thing to do. If you unavoidably have an `str`, and you're using `shell=True` (or you're on Windows), just pass the `str`. If you do have to split the string, then yes, definitely use `shlex.split` rather than `str.split`. But that should be your last resort, not your first. In this case, there's no reason for any splitting.

Comment: another issue is that `shlex.split()` does not emulate the shell perfectly. [It may break in subtle ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468807/python-executing-a-shell-command/28468860#comment45287698_28468860). As @abarnert said: construct the list explicitly instead of using `shlex.split()`.

Answer (score 2):

it is not to compecated execute above command in python:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sort','-k1','1', '-k4','4n', '-k5','5n',    '+outpath+fnametempout+', '>', '+outpath+fnameout'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
subprocess.call(['ps','aux'])
lines=subprocess.check_output(['ls','-al'])
line_list = lines.split('\n')

or

handle = subprocess.Popen('ls',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
handle.stdout.read()
```

Comment: OPs issue is the presence of `>` shell redirection operator while `subprocess` does not use the shell by default. And the solution is to use `stdout=fout` as demonstrated by @mgilson. Don't use `out = handle.stdout.read()` if you've used `PIPE` several times, use `out ,err = handle.communicate(input)` instead -- otherwise the subprocess may deadlock (though it is unlikely with `ls` here)