# Python redirection in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, split, subprocess, io-redirection

I want to use a bash command using python's `subprocess.Popen`.
My bash command looks like:

```
$ gunzip -c /my/dir/file1.gz /my/dir/file2.gz | gsplit -l 500000 --numerical-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=3 --additional-suffix=.split - /my/dir/output/file_
```

It takes compressed files, uncompresses them, merges the content, splits the content into output files. I can do that in Python this way:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
dir = "/my/dir"
files = ["file1.gz", "file2.gz"]
 
cmd1 = "gunzip -c {}".format(" ".join([dir+files[0], dir+files[1]]))
cmd2 = "{} -l {} --numeric-suffixes={} --suffix-length={} --additional-suffix={}  - {}"\
        .format("gsplit", 500000, 1, 3, ".split"#, "'gzip > $FILE.gz'"
                , "/my/dir/output/file_")
  
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd1).split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd2).split(), stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close()
proc2.wait()
print("result:", proc2.returncode)
```

Then I can check the output:

```
$ ls /my/dir/output
file_001.split
file_002.split
file_003.split
```

Now I want to make use of the gsplit's  `--filter` argument, which allows to pipe the result to another command. Here, I chose gzip as I want to compress the output. Bash command looks like this:

```
$ gunzip -c /my/dir/file1.gz /my/dir/file2.gz | gsplit -l 500000 --numerical-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=3 --additional-suffix=.split --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' - /my/dir/output/file_
```

This command works.

Now putting it into python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
dir = "/my/dir"
files = ["file1.gz", "file2.gz"]
 
cmd1 = "gunzip -c {}".format(" ".join([dir+files[0], dir+files[1]]))
cmd2 = "{} -l {} --numeric-suffixes={} --suffix-length={} --additional-suffix={}  --filter={} - {}"\
        .format("gsplit", 500000, 1, 3, ".split", "'gzip > $FILE.gz'"
                , "/my/dir/output/file_")
  
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd1).split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd2).split(), stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close()
proc2.wait()
print("result:", proc2.returncode)
```

Alas I get this error:

> /usr/local/bin/gsplit: invalid option -- 'f'
>
> Try '/usr/local/bin/gsplit --help' for more information.
>
> gunzip: error writing to output: Broken pipe
>
> gunzip: /my/dir/file1.gz: uncompress failed
>
> gunzip: error writing to output: Broken pipe
>
> gunzip: /my/dir/file12.gz: uncompress failed

I think it has to do with the redirection symbol in `gzip > $FILE.gz`.

What is going on, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you hardcode the command as a list (instead of doing format and then split) does it work? I think split splits your filter apart into `["--filter='gzip", ">", "$FILE.gz'"]` which is not what you want.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline. alternately, you may want to try using `shell=True`, which should actually start bash instead of the exact commands, and let you put the entire line (with pipes, redirects, and all - which are shell functions anyways, not part of the called executables) as is....

Comment: Aside: why do you call `str(cmd2).split()` rather than `cmd2.split()`? Since `cmd2` is already a `str` what does the extra function call get?

Comment: @Robᵩ: I actually used this chunk in a function, I used the str() to make sure the argument was a string. But here in my example it is totally irrelevant you are right

Comment: @Corley Brigman: I changed from the `subprocess.call()` to `subprocess.Popen()` to track the exit status when piping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split()` isn't the appropriate function to convert a command-line string into an array of arguments. To see why, try:

```
print(str(cmd2).split())
```

Notice that `"'gzip` `>`, and `$FILE.gz'"` are in distinct arguments.

Try:

```
#UNTESTED
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd2), stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, it did the trick! I was totally careless on that split.. I just brainlessly added the filter argument without questioning the behaviour resulting from the split. My bad

Comment: @kaligne: 1- [`shlex.split()` can be fooled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386775/subprocess-call/14386815#comment45736245_14386815) 2- I don't see how it helps with `$FILE`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: well i used a simple str().split on the command which messed the string "gzip > $FILE.gz" up in that sense that I did not intend to split it based on spaces (and that's my bad). So `shlex.split()` DID help. However could you develop why and how it could be fooled? What is the alternative?

Comment: Sorry I read your reply on my phone, the link was not coloured then... Thanks anyway